# Perl one liner working with >> but not >

Tags: files, perl

I'm running the following command to add line numbers:

```
perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"'
```

I can append the results to a file with:

```
cat test.txt | perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' >> test.txt
```

But if I try to replace the current contents the file ends up blank:

```
cat test.txt | perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' > test.txt
```

Why is this?

Comment: for in place editing, just use `perl -i -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' test.txt`... also there is a command `nl` for numbering purposes